# Web site Header tag links some resources with HTTPS

Tags: themes, https

in my WP installation with Quest 1.2.X theme I'm getting the web pages with some  and  tags (included in the header) with HTTPS url instead of the default one HTTP.

Some of the urls are:

- https://xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/quest/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
- https://xxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js

There is not HTTPS in my web site, why the URL of some resources are printed out with HTTPS ?

Thanks, F.